# Unable to resolve GroovyClassLoader

Tags: java, gradle

Currently I am trying to build a gradle based project. Objective of the project is to invoke Groovy code from Java.

Reason:
Existing project is in Groovy and slowly wish to move it to Java.
To start need to verify how easy/difficult it is to invoke existing code modules written in Groovy from Java.

Issue:
On manually adding the import statement:

**The import groovy cannot be resolved**

While adding class name without adding import:

**Unable to resolve GroovyClassLoader**

```
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import groovy.lang.*;

public class Test{
    private final URLClassLoader loader = null;

    public Test() {
        //this.loader = new GroovyClassLoader();
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
//implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.8'
implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.8', ext: 'pom'

}
```

Error:

```
The import groovy cannot be resolved
```

Any help/guidance will help. Please guide me if I am missing out on any aspect.

**Project Info :**

**Gradle version**: 7.0

**JDK** : 1.8

**IDE** : Eclipse

Comment: Is this in Java code? Do you have the appropriate `import`? Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As per documentation http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html  this class is available under groovy.lang
But I do not see it available for my gradle project.

This error is compile time error. code is as simple as:
`code`


public class Test {

    private final GroovyClassLoader loader;

}

`code`

Comment: please edit your question to include the code. Also, I don't see an `import` in that code.

Comment: What does that mean, can you help with which import should be included here? That is the ask.

In java you have to specify the dependency first. Which is the dependency required for this class? I have included the dependency included currently, i.e., groovy-all .

Hope you are aware of gradle and java, otherwise it would be difficult to answer what I am looking for.

Comment: The full name of the class is `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader`. You simply wrote `GroovyClassLoader`. Without an `import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;` at the beginning of your file this won't work. That is true for **all** classes in all packages (with the exception of `java.lang` and the current package of a class).

Comment: Cool. So, you are not getting my point. 
I can import only when the corresponding dependency is available under my project.

So, from the link I pasted, yes this import is required. Clear.

But even after adding groovy-all dependency under my project, I do not see this class available for import.

My ask is which dependency if not 'groovy-all' to be included for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "do not see this class available for import"? Just write the import. If it's there and not working, you'll see an error message that should be clear. And honestly: the reason I do not get your point is that you're not doing a great job explaining what you have tried. Such as: provide the **actual code that you are trying and not some estimation**.

Comment: @JoachimSauer : No game going on. But hope you have worked on gradle and java enough to understand and comprehend the problem. Hope you are able to comment now as I have fulfilled your ask.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to answer someone trying to help **you**. That said, the import is not being detected, are you sure you have the correct classpath defined

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with your description. I've created a simple project with just `groovy-all` as dependency and a simple Test class that references `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader` and it compiles just fine.

Comment: Is this something to do with Eclipse IDE?
Do you mind letting me know what IDE are you using and if you used gradle for the same?

Answer (score 0):

@Joachim Sauer  Thanks for your responses. It prompted me to try out the same code under a new gradle project.

As I tried it in a new project, it worked.

Apologies to all as I am yet to identify the reason for this issue. I am still trying to identify the RC. Only issue I could identify as of now is that for some reason gradle refresh was not working for that project and was not updating the Project Dependencies (not downloading). Hence not finding the library for import leading to the issue.

(Gradle version is same under both projects)